# Parametrization of torus-like object

Tags: manifolds, surfaces, parametrization

I'm trying to parameterize this surface so that I can have a geometric description of it and to find some closed geodesics on it.

> How do you parameterize this surface?

[image]

The *central* cross section is defined as $\log^2 x +\log^2 y=1.$

I can parameterize this by $(e^{\cos(t)},e^{\sin(t)}).$ I'm having trouble parameterizing the surface though. I know that the surface is generated by taking the cross section and having another copy perpendicular to it, similar to the way the torus is generated with two circles being perpendicular and revolving them.

Comment: Did you see that it looks like $\displaystyle\cos^{2}\left(t\right) + \sin^{2}\left(t\right) = 1$.

Comment: @FelixMarin I see that now yes

Comment: How does the cross section vary with $z$?  You've shown a picture of a surface in three dimensions, but only given an equation related to two of them.  Is it something like $\log^2 x + \log^2 y = 1 - z^2$?

Comment: @geocalc33: Plotting to limits $(u, 0,  2 \pi), (v, -\pi/3, \pi/3)$ some /pinched edges are seen at three  corners.. that should contain geodesics. btw what constants $h,k$  produce a circular torus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing in *Wolfram Mathematica 12.2*:

```
r[u_] = {Exp[Cos[u]], Exp[Sin[u]], 0}
    
t[u_] = Simplify[r'[u] / Sqrt[Total[r'[u]^2]], 0 < u < 2π]
n[u_] = Simplify[t'[u] / Sqrt[Total[t'[u]^2]], 0 < u < 2π]
b[u_] = Simplify[Cross[t[u], n[u]], 0 < u < 2π]

s[u_, v_] = r[u] + h Exp[Cos[v]] n[u] + k Exp[Sin[v]] b[u]

{h, k} = {1/6, 1/5};
ParametricPlot3D[s[u, v], {u, 0, 2π}, {v, 0, 2π}]
```

we get:

$$
\small
\begin{aligned}
& \mathbf{r}(u) = \left(e^{\cos u},\;e^{\sin u},\;0\right) \\
\\
& \hat{\mathbf{t}}(u) = \left(-\frac{\left(e^{\cos u}\,\sin u\right)}{\sqrt{\left(e^{\sin u}\,\cos u\right)^2 + \left(e^{\cos u}\,\sin u\right)^2}}, \; \frac{\left(e^{\sin u}\,\cos u\right)}{\sqrt{\left(e^{\sin u}\,\cos u\right)^2 + \left(e^{\cos u}\,\sin u\right)^2}}, \; 0\right) \\
\\
& \hat{\mathbf{n}}(u) = \left(-\frac{\left(e^{\sin u}\,\cos u\right)}{\sqrt{\left(e^{\sin u}\,\cos u\right)^2 + \left(e^{\cos u}\,\sin u\right)^2}}, \; -\frac{\left(e^{\cos u}\,\sin u\right)}{\sqrt{\left(e^{\sin u}\,\cos u\right)^2 + \left(e^{\cos u}\,\sin u\right)^2}}, \; 0\right) \\
\\
& \hat{\mathbf{b}}(u) = \left(0,\;0,\;1\right) \\
\\ 
& \mathbf{s}(u,\,v) = \left(e^{\cos u} - \frac{h\,e^{\cos v}\left(e^{\sin u}\,\cos u\right)}{\sqrt{\left(e^{\sin u}\,\cos u\right)^2 + \left(e^{\cos u}\,\sin u\right)^2}}, \; e^{\sin u} - \frac{h\,e^{\cos v}\left(e^{\cos u}\,\sin u\right)}{\sqrt{\left(e^{\sin u}\,\cos u\right)^2 + \left(e^{\cos u}\,\sin u\right)^2}}, \; k\,e^{\sin v}\right) \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

with $0 \le u \le 2\pi$ and $0 \le v \le 2\pi$ (moreover, I chose $h = 1/6$ and $k = 1/5$):

[image]

which seems to me to be of the desired type.

Comment: In $\mathbf{s}(u,\,v)$ you have $h\,e^{\cos v}\left(e^{\cos u}\,\sin u\right).$ Should the $\cos(u)$ be a $\sin(u)$?